# ls gives me "illegal option"

Tags: ls, zsh

I recently installed `zsh` and now whenever I `ls` or `ls -l` or `ls anything` I get "illegal option". Not sure where to start looking to fix this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Run `which ls` to see what exactly is ran why you type ls. `ls` may be configured as an alias with options not available on your system.

Comment: Yup, it was configured with --color=auto. Replaced with -G and it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Might be a broken alias. Try /bin/ls

Comment: How does one mean the alias? Hoping you're still kicking around from answering this 14 years ago 

Comment: All good now! I'm using fish shell and found I can just write `alias ls="/bin/ls"` to get the `ls` command working

Comment: @ckhatton Glad you made it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

tip:

if you even find yourself without /bin/ls , (recovery limited shell / corruption / meltdown) then you can use

```
echo *
```

which will display file and directories in the current directory (it's not pretty, but it works!)

as echo is a shell built in, it will always work, without the help of external unix tools :-)

try

```
type echo
```

echo is a shell builtin

here a short list of the bash built-in's (I don't have zsh installed)

```
bash defines the following built-in commands: :, ., [, alias, bg, bind,
   break,  builtin,  case,  cd,  command,  compgen,  complete,   continue,
   declare,  dirs, disown, echo, enable, eval, exec, exit, export, fc, fg,
   getopts, hash, help, history, if, jobs, kill, let, local, logout, popd,
   printf,  pushd, pwd, read, readonly, return, set, shift, shopt, source,
   suspend, test, times, trap,  type,  typeset,  ulimit,  umask,  unalias,
   unset, until, wait, while.
```